# segmentation fault in C, can't figure out the reason

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

The function below should change to uppercase all the occurrence of the second string in the first.
When it matches the first letter it should point p to its position in the first string and then check the remaining part of the match string. If a match occurs it substitutes every character with its uppercase version. 
When I try to access the values to which p points I get "segmentation fault"
I know there are many things wrong with this program: I could just store the position of the first character in i and use i+j as an index for the first string. I also don't check if the second string contains only letters.
Anyway, I really want to know what's wrong with that use of pointers in this specific case even if I can rewrite a better version of it.

```
char *matchToUp(char *s, char *match)
{
    int i = 0, j=0;
    char *p = s;

    while (s[i] != '\0')
    {
        while(s[i]!= match[0] && s[i]!= '\0')
        {

            i++;
        }
        printf("%d", i);
        p = &s[i];
        while (match[j] != '\0' &&p[j] == match[j])
        {
            j++;
        }
        if(match[j] == '\0')
        {
            printf("%d", j);
            while(j >= 0)
            {
                p[j] = (char) toupper((unsigned int) p[j]);
                j--;
                i++;

            }
        }
        else
        {
            j=0;
            i++;

        }
    }


    return s;
}
```

Comment: The source of the problem is in the caller (well, and in this function too, as it is not sanity-checking the data passed to it. )

Comment: Run it through valgrind and/or gdb and see what you get.

Comment: char *p;
p = matchToUp(" abcde", "abc");

I should sanity check the data, that's right, but I added "de" just to be sure and the problem isn't the fact the address is out of bounds

I use Code::Blocks, does the code work outside the ide?

Comment: So you are attempting to modify a read-only string literal by assigning `p[..]`.

Comment: So that's the problem!
I forgot string literals are read-only. What should I do? should I allocate memory for a copy of the first string just to be safe and return a pointer to the modified string?

Comment: You certainly should allocate the memory *somewhere*..

Comment: The `while(s[i]!= match[0] && s[i]!= '\0'){i++}` loop will find the next first matching character, or the end of your input string.  But after you finish that loop you are only dealing with the first character matches case, not the end of input string.  So off you go, past the end.

Comment: I fixed the loop and modified the function so that it copies the first argument to dinamically allocated memory and now it works.

Comment: @MatSiv97 `char* matchToUp(char *s, char *match)` to be on the safe side you should pass and check the length of each buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Segmentation faults occur when a function (or a process) tries to access memory that is out of it's bound. 
In this case, it looks like you're passing a pointer into the function (`*s`). If the caller hasn't allocated the space for that string on the heap using `malloc` then the variable is by default on the `stack` of the calling function. 
Each function gets its own `stack frame`, accessing memory outside of your stack frame will cause a `segmentation fault`. So when passing `s*` into this function, you're (potentially, I would have to see the caller to know for sure :)) passing a pointer to a char array that is not a part of your stack frame. Thus you're getting a `segmentation fault` because you're trying to access something at address `s*[j]`, but this function isn't allowed to access that space.

Comment: I passed a string literal as an argument and tried to modify it without allocating memory.

Comment: ah yeah, that'd do it too :)

Answer (score 0):

You start doing the toupper stuff one element of,  in your code p[j] points at the first call one after the match.

Comment: yes, that's true, but I fixed it by testing for j>0 and decrementing j before accessing p[j] and it still doesn't work